# Error in c++ with regular expression

Tags: c++, regex

When I try to make this pattern in c++ the compiler gives me a runtime error

```
regex IntegerWSign("^((-)|(\+))[0-9]{1,}$");
```

Comment: Remember, in string literals all `'\'` characters need to be escaped.

Comment: sorry I didnt understand it can you explain

Comment: Btw `{1,}` can be replaced by `+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\+` is the valid notation in a regular expression, but inside a C++ string that needs to be `\\+`.

Your expression was being interpreted as:

```
^((-)|(+))[0-9]{1,}$
```

Where that's not valid.

Comment: thank you  for explanation it works

Comment: Or you could just use a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)..